# Cropping Google Map

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to crop the Google Map before integrating it into an application?

For example, my city will be the only area visible when I launch the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to crop an area or any part of Maps, 
 you can show your area initially when user view your app & disable navigating within the map by `setClickable(false);`

```
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    List<overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "This is my area");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(6);
```

where `latitudeE6, longitudeE6` is your area's lat & Long